# c# DateTimePicker Control Blur on Selected Dates

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Does anyone know how to get rid of the annoying blur that takes place when selecting a range of dates on the DateTimePicker Calendar control like in the image below :-

[image: DateTime Calendar Control]

It's far from presentable like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MonthCalendar control selection range with EnableVisualStyles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207306/monthcalendar-control-selection-range-with-enablevisualstyles)

Comment: Pretty sure you are describing the MonthCalendar control and not the DateTimePicker control.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get some suitable result playing with the TitleForeColor and TitleBackColor properties. At least you'll be able to see the dates.

Comment: I'll accept that as Useful, Its certainly enhanced the control by changing the BackColor to white, and ForeColor to Black. I'd like to be able to change the colour of the Selection if possible.