# Programmatically setting back color to specific days in a calender for windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a windows application in which I make use of the default calender for appointment purpose. I wanted to examine each day of the calender and set a background color to some of them to distinguish it from the rest of the dates, such as available, appointment closed, holidays etc.

I have searched and found that using `OnDayRender` event to change the `BackColor` of certain days is possible. But what I understood is it is available only for web forms not for the window form. Is there a solution for the same or any alternative way to implement the same in winforms? (Such as using an embedded WPF control etc.)

Comment: there several examples of this on the web..have you actually performed a `Google` search..? here is a coded project you can utilize code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar

Comment: Thank you MethodMan! I successfully did that. But the control takes too long to respond. Any Help ??

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
DateTime someDate = new DateTime(); //or an array of dates, then run a loop

private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (monthCalendar1.SelectionStart == someDate)
    {
        monthCalendar1.BackColor = SystemColors.someColor;
    }
    else
    {
        monthCalendar1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do that in WinForms.

One option is to create your own calendar that inherits from the `MonthCalendar` control. You will have to override `OnPaint` method. In the method you have to localize a `Rectangle` for each date you want to change the background for and then change it (the background). An example of creating your own calendar control with `OnPaint` and `WndProc` overriden can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410399/3330348). The example doesn't do exactly what you want but is a good start.

There is however another option. You are not the first person searching for this functionality in the calendar control. And so someone already created a highly customizable WinForms calendar. It does what you want and much more. It's called [Another Month Calendar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar).

Comment: Thank you, Another Month Calender is the solution what I needed. But it takes too much time to Respond, How to solve that?